# Why Resource Class is not being included in new CosmosDB V3 SDK, which was there in old CosmosDB SDK?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

We are upgrading our code from old [CosmosDB V2 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet) to new [V3 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet-standard). We had used this [Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource?view=azure-dotnet#:%7E:text=Definition&text=Represents%20an%20abstract%20resource%20type,Document%20extend%20this%20abstract%20type.) as a base class to all the models which we are saving in cosmos db because of their automatic Id generation as well as Timestamp properties.

I could not find [Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource?view=azure-dotnet#:%7E:text=Definition&text=Represents%20an%20abstract%20resource%20type,Document%20extend%20this%20abstract%20type.) Class which was part of old Cosmos DB SDK in the new SDK V3. I could only find 2 similar classes [Database properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.databaseproperties?view=azure-dotnet) class [Container properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.containerproperties?view=azure-dotnet) class. But I am not sure if i should use them or create my own base class.

I know I can create my own base class, but i just don't want to do that unless it is already not available in the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this Answer in the GitHub Repo from @j82w !! Thanks to @j82w for the answer

TLDR: v3 does not have the equivalent Resource as a base class.

The reasons why:

1. Auto id generation was causing a lot of confusion, and often caused
   customers to design inefficient workflows. For example there was
   several customers doing a query later to find the item instead of
   just doing a point read. Doing a query is far more expensive and
   slower compared to a point reads. By the time customers realized
   this there application was in production and making it far more
   painful process to fix.
2. In v3 SDK it allows custom serializer, so you could use the new
   `System.Text.Json` library. Having a base Resource class would make
   it dependent on the current `Newtonsoft` default.
3. This also provides a better ownership model as you don't have to
   change your models in the future when you move to the v4 SDK when it
   is released.
4. We also found most users did not need all the properties or were not
   using the class at all. It was a simple enough class that any user
   that did need it could easy create their own without taking a
   dependency on the SDK.

*check the [Answer on the Git Hub Repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1694)*